# How to set the amount of time delay before Mac sleeps in macOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos, mac, sleep-wake, settings, sonoma

In macOS Sonoma, I cannot find the Settings panel for changing the amount of time delay to wait before sleeping the MacBook Pro M1 Pro 16”.

Search for "sleep", or "energy", does not help.

Comment: What if you search on "battery" (you don't mention what Mac it is so I am assuming it's a MacBook of some sort)

Answer (score 0):

That setting has not changed for years.

Click on Apple (top left)

Click on System Preference

Click on Battery

Select battery and set the timer